# Limit Evaluation of the form inf/inf

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x^\alpha} ; \quad \alpha >0$$

Wouldn't it be just zero because $x^\alpha$ will reach $\infty$ much earlier than $\log(x)$?

I tried using L'Hospital's rule but was not able to figure it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: L'Hopital should work just fine here

Comment: What did you get when you applied L'Hopital's Rule?  It sounds as if you made an error in application or interpreting the result, but there is no way to help with that because you have chosen to hide your work and result.

Comment: I got the same result as David.

Comment: Jut to clarify, the equation $\lim\limits _{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\log x} {x^a} =0,a>0$ is expressed in informal/crude language as "logarithm goes to infinity much slower than any polynomial function" and hence the latter can't be used as a justification for the former.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\log$ means the natural logarithm, L'Hospital's gives

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x^\alpha }=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1/x}{\alpha x^{\alpha-1} }=\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x^{\alpha} }$$

Comment: I also got the same thing but what can I do now?

Comment: @Leaderboard281923 : So the limit is $0. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Without L'Hospital:

Any high-school student has learnt that $\;\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln x}x=0$ (which is proved without the help of the not-so-divine Marquis…).

Now $\ln x=\frac 1\alpha\ln(x^\alpha)$, so, setting $u=x^\alpha$, $\lim_{x\to \infty}u=\infty$, and
$$\frac{\ln x}{x^\alpha}=\frac1\alpha\frac{\ln u}u\xrightarrow[u\to \infty]{}\frac1\alpha\cdot 0=0.$$

In the same vein, it is easy to show that for any $\alpha,\beta>0$, one has

> $\qquad\qquad\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^\beta
> > x}{x^\alpha}=0,\quad\text{i.e.}\quad \ln^\beta
> > x=_{\infty}o\bigl(x^\alpha\bigr).$

Comment: In fact, this is true for all $\beta\in\mathbb{R}, \alpha>0$.

Comment: @bjorn93: Yes, but if $\beta\le 0$, we don't have to state it as a result – it is no more an indeterminate form.